# If I'm working on a web app, do I ask here?

Tags: discussion, scope

If I'm writing/developing a web app, do I post questions here? Or is it just for 'users' or client-programmers of existing web apps?

Comment: See [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)

Answer (score 14):

WebApps is geared towards end-users of web applications.  Depending on your question, it might be a better fit for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (if programming related) or [Web Masters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (if related to running/operating a website)